# htaccess seamlessly redirect to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a multilanguage website powered by one single CMS installation. The relevant language is triggered by URI, so domain.com/pt show Portuguese while domain.com/en English.

I want however to have two different domains, so portuguese.com shows what preciously was under domain.com/pt and english.com shows what was under domain.com/en.

I already have the two domains linked to the same account, but at this stage they don't really affect the language. So english.com/pt will show the Portuguese version of the website while portuguese.com/en will show the English version.

How can I edit my htaccess so english.com acts as both portuguese.com/en and english.com/en on server side but user sees .english.com? The same goes to portuguese.com.

Here is my current code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^english\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.english\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.english\.com\/en\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portuguese.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.portuguese.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I've tried many pieces of codes I found online but none of them seem to work!

Comment: Where is your current .htaccess code?

Comment: I've updated it above. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 rules below your current rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?portuguese\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!pt/).*) /pt/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?english\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!en/).*) /en/$1 [L,NC]
```